# automatic adjustment of mat-table rows if needed

Tags: css, angular, mat-table

I want to adjust the height of the lines of an angular6 mat-table to the content (as you can see in the attached graphic).

Intention of the whole thing: 
I want to have the first DialectLanguage in the cell first, followed by 1-* corresponding ids.
Then in the same cell I want to list all other DialectLanguages and their Ids and so on...

[image: ILLUSTRATION]

```js
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="germanEntry">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>German</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.germanEntry }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="germanId">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>German ID</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.germanId }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="references">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>References to other Languages</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <span *ngFor="
            let item of element.reverseTranslations;
            let i = index;
            let isLast = last
          ">
         {{ item.reverseGerman2DialectLanguage }} <br >

          <span style="display:block;" *ngFor="let innerItem of item.reverseGerman2DialectIdList" let j="index;" let
            isInnerLast="last">
            {{ innerItem }}
            <!-- Comma and space will be appended to all entries except the last one : -->
            <span *ngIf="!isInnerLast">,&nbsp;</span>

          </span>
        </span></mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

 // 
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

At the moment new entries of the corresponding cells are moved to the right when the cell is full.

What can I do as a newbie in CSS to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you may wrap inner item to another span and add style display:block; code.

```
<span style="display:block;" *ngFor="let innerItem of item.reverseGerman2DialectIdList" let j="index;" let isInnerLast="last">
  {{ innerItem }}
  <!-- Comma and space will be appended to all entries except the last one : -->
      <span *ngIf="!isInnerLast">,&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

I created a sample here to help you more.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZOi00Rpa5Vl7GmrjvkN3?p=preview

Hope it helps you!

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your answer. it helped me very much to find the final solution

Answer (score 1):

As somebody may have the same problem in the future, I am going to post my final solution.
Thanks to @itsmeniel, who helped me to the right direction!

References to other Languages
      
        
          {{ item.reverseGerman2DialectLanguage }}:

```
      <span style="display:block;" *ngFor="let innerItem of item.reverseGerman2DialectIdList; last as isInnerLast">
        {{innerItem}}
        <!-- Comma and space will be appended to all entries except the last one : -->
        <span *ngIf="!isInnerLast">,&nbsp;</span>

      </span>
    </span>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```